# Formatting a variable in Django and autofields

Tags: python, django, string-formatting

I have this problem I've been trying to tackle for a while.  I have a variable that is 17 characters long, and when displaying the variable on my form, I want it to display the last seven characters of this variable in bold...how do I go about this...I'd really appreciate anybody's insight on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ thevar|slice:":-7" }}<b>{{ thevar|slice:"-7:" }}</b>
```

The `slice` built-in filter in Django templates acts like slicing does in Python, so that for example `s[:-7]` is the string excluding its last 7 characters and `s[-7:]` is the substring formed by just the last 7 characters.

Comment: SWEET...didn't know this, though I knew there was some variable to do this

Comment: Yeah, Django templating has a LOT of useful built-in tags and filters, and many map aspects of Python's functionality (though it's sometimes maddening for a Python programmer to remember "how do you say this in the Django templating language";-).